# Program picking '\0' even when it is not mentioned - Clarification

Tags: c++, arrays

So, I am given to predict what this program will do:

```
int main()
{
   char d[] = {'h','e','l','l','o'};
   const char *c = d;
   std::cout << *c << std::endl;
   while ( *c ) {
      c = c + 1;
      std::cout << *c << std::endl;
      if ( *c == '\0' )
         std::cout << "Yes" << std::endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

From my understanding the code should've never printed **Yes** as there is no `\0` in the character array `d[]`, so is it the garbage value this program is picking? I short this while should run infinite times. Is that right?

Comment: This program has undefined behavior caused by reading past the end of `d`. As such, it would be allowed to print `Yes` as many times as it feels like.

Comment: *I short*?? Did you mean *I thought*?

Comment: Surely on a typical, modern machine it is nearly certain that it will quickly encounter either some byte that happens to be zero or some try to read from some address outside the range the program is permitted to access.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proper answer to this question is that the program exhibits undefined behavior, because it goes past the end of the array.

Changing the program to use string literal for initialization would change the behavior to "always prints `"Yes"`:

```
char d[] = "hello";
```

> I short this while should run infinite times.

Once undefined behavior happens, all bets are off. However, commonly the program manages to find a zero byte in memory outside of `d[]`, at which point it prints `"Yes"`, and exits the loop.

Comment: always prints "Yes"-> is it due to the anomaly introduced after the undefined  behavior? How does that happen?

Comment: @Gaurav it's _probably_ going to print "Yes" at some point because of the likelihood of a null byte in memory.

Comment: @Gaurav The likelihood of finding a zero byte in memory is pretty high, especially considering the presence of multi-byte numbers that store small numbers, pointers with alignment at 16-byte boundary, etc. That has nothing to do with undefined behavior, only a practical observation.

Answer (score -2):

Your code is an example where array `d` is not a string (more accurately, not a nul-termitated string), so it is incorrect usage of that array as a string. That means, all functions that work with `char*` strings and use `\0` as a sign of string end go ouside the memory allocated for `d`.... and somtimes `\0` can be found outside (no one knows beforehand where this `\0` will be found). And once again, this is incorrect usage that can lead to errors related to array boundaries violation.

Finaly, because conditions for `if` statement and `while` is "associated" in sense **"(*c == '\0') is true at the last iteration of loop while(*c){...}"** and there is very low probability that `while(*c){...}` is infinite, "yes" will be printed eventually.

**UPDATE:**

Let's consider additionally the following example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char d1[] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' }; // no nul-terminator here

    char d2[] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };

    char d3[] = "hello";

    cout << "Memory allocated for d1 - " << sizeof(d1) << endl;
    cout << "Length of string in  d1 - " << strlen(d1) << endl;
    cout << "Memory allocated for d2 - " << sizeof(d2) << endl;
    cout << "Length of string in  d2 - " << strlen(d2) << endl;
    cout << "Memory allocated for d3 - " << sizeof(d3) << endl;
    cout << "Length of string in  d3 - " << strlen(d3) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output will be (for the second line not always exactly, but similar):

> Memory allocated for d1 - 5
>
> Length of string in  d1 - 19
>
> Memory allocated for d2 - 6
>
> Length of string in  d2 - 5
>
> Memory allocated for d3 - 6
>
> Length of string in  d3 - 5

Here you can see 3 ways of char-array initialization. And `d3` here is initialized with string literal where `\0` is added because value is in `""`. Array `d1` has no nul-terminator and as a result `strlen` return value greated than `sizeof` - `\0` was found outside array `d1`.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: I don't think OP was asking why his string had no `\0`. It looks like he constructed his example specifically to avoid having a `\0` so he could illustrate the actual question.

Comment: @Angew Yes, this is the answer, is not it?